# Upgrade Apache from v2.4.6 to as newer version as possible - CentoOS 7

Tags: apache-httpd

I searched all over but could not find an easy way to upgrade Apache without recompiling. I installed httpd24 from [this](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/httpd24/) instructions but could not figure out how to replace httpd with httpd24.

**Is there a way to update repositories and use yum to handle Apache upgrade?**

Being a production server, I would like to keep things straightforward so that security patches can be automatically applied.

I was able to upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.1.0.

What prompted me to upgrade:
I want the server to be up to date with security. I am also working towards a A+ score at www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. I am currently at A. I see these 2 messages: *This site works only in browsers with SNI support.* and *Client does not support DH parameters > 1024 bits.* DHParameters (4096) is created in the server but...

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem"
```

...does not work in Apache 2.4.6 and I do not want to add it to site ssl certificate as it gets updated automatically by Let's Encrypt.

Comment: I don't think that "Client does not support DH parameters > 1024 bits" is the reason to not get A+. Allowing DH parameters <= 1024 bits is insecure and your server would be insecurely used by such clients. This should result in less than A rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Hat/CentOS often makes updates to software by backporting those changes into previous version (i.e. it updates the current version but doesn't change the actual version number).  httpd-2.4.6 is the latest available 'version' of httpd for CentOS 7.

Checking the announcements list, the latest update for httpd on CentOS 7 is [CESA-2016:1422](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2016-July/021979.html).

Follow the links, in particular, go to the corresponding Red Hat errata, then down to the CVE section for [1353755](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1353755).  If you read through the bugzilla report, you will see that these latest fixes have been applied to httpd-2.4.6.40 for Red Hat/CentOS.  It also mentions that ASF plans to address the issues in 2.4.24.

The latest Apache httpd is [2.4.23](http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/httpd/).  Given that, if you are running httpd-2.4.6-40 on CentOS 7, you have the latest and greatest version of httpd for CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

RE: getting A+ at www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ I was missing this option:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
```

So, to get A+ score add all of these params to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
```